# Suitable motor for pic WAKING project

Tags: microcontroller, pic, motor

Since my sleeping is very deeply, I can't wake up with alarm clock, I thought for a simple PIC-microcontroller project to wake me up. I will suspend a "bucket" full of water from the ceiling above my bed, and at a certain specific time, the PIC will move a motor that causes the water to fall on me :D :D.

But that is not a joke!!

Actually I can write some simple programs with mikroC for dimming a LED, making sound frequences, switches, transistors and relays, for example.

I have searched the web, found many motor types: DC, AC, servo and stepper, but have no idea about the suitable one for my project (it should be able to load a fully bucket). I want also to know how to run it.

Any help would be appropriated
Regards

**EDIT:**
I want the water to fall by degrees, hence the motor, not toppling it directly.

Comment: Between us, this is more of a robotics question, and we don't do that anymore. Just electrons, you know, with the purple polka dots on them. So the question is likely to be closed. I hear they're working on a robotics site.

Comment: What is a bail of water?  Straw and hay comes in bails - water comes in buckets, jars, etc.

Comment: @Matt You likely have experience of farming :) thanks!

Comment: Why not weave a grid of fine wires into your bottom sheet - that way you can shock yourself into wakefulness.  It's hard to sleep when you're being mildly electrocuted.

Comment: @Matt this level may come after the water has dropped, the bed become more conductance so that electrocution is better

Comment: Hydraulic ram under one edge of the bed to flip it over?

Comment: That sounds like better :)

Comment: @MattJenkins let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/869/discussion-between-mr-ddd-and-matt-jenkins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is to have a stock of dry pillows.

A motor for this is overkill. You don't want to actively rotate the bucket, leave that to **gravity**. Better to **balance it** against some rest, so that removing the rest will topple it. You can use a **solenoid** for this, or maybe a **servo** (but then we're using a motor again).

[image]

To solve the **humidity problem**: don't fill the bucket with water, but when you balance it, don't tie it, so that it comes down itself. No dry pillow stock needed. :-)

**edit**
Since you want a slow release of the water you'll need a motor to control the rotation. Use a **DC motor** with a **reduction gearbox**. You'll find those on any robotics website.

[image]

Another solution, which is **mechanically simpler** is to use a **electric water valve**; the bucket can then remain in place. You can find such a valve in an old dishwasher or washing machine. The water valve will probably release too much water, but you can reduce this to **drop level** by closing the outlet, just leaving a small opening, so that there will only be a few drops released.

Comment: Ok, so the suitable motor is the servo?

Comment: Or the solenoid. When it's activated it pulls the shaft in, so that the bail's rest is removed and it topples over. With a servo you could do the same thing, but then the movement is rotational instead of linear. Servos will be easier to find.

Comment: There are also solenoids which pull *out* when activated, so be sure to pick the right model, otherwise you'll have to have it activated all the time.

Comment: Btw you can get some pretty tough solenoids from pinball machine parts stores.

Comment: @stevenvh can I control that solenoid by the PIC? Can it fall the water by degrees?

Comment: The PIC can't drive the solenoid directly; it requires to much current. You'll need a transistor. Here on EE you'll find examples how to drive a relay from a microcontroller, it's the same schematic. "fall by degrees", you mean have complete control over the released amount of water? No, the solenoid will pull back or not, it's an on/off device. I edited my answer.